# error in boot.ci, boot R package - Redux

Tags: r

I am bootstrapping IRT parameter estimates for 15 different unitary dimensions. I use the following code for each dimension (swapping out relevant changes of variables and data frames)

```
BS <- function(formula, data, indices) {

d <- data[indices, drop=FALSE] # allows boot to select sample

fit <- ltm(DIM1A_IRT_Vars ~ z1, IRT.param=TRUE, start.val="random", na.action=NULL, control=list(GHk=35, iter.em=100, verbose=TRUE))
  return(coef(fit))
      } 

bootDIM1A <- boot(data=DIM1A_IRT_Vars, statistic=BS, R=500, sim="ordinary")
#Ordinary nonparametric = empirical bootstrap
print(bootDIM1A, digits=10)
plot(bootDIM1A, index=1, qdist="norm")#index= refers to that coefficient in the list
boot.ci(bootDIM1A, type="all", index=10)#index= refers to that coefficient in the list
```

For 12 of these models, I have no problems when invoking the boot.ci or boot.plot functions and everything is quite fine in terms of generating the desired results. However, for three of the dimensions, I get the following:

for boot.ci: [1] "All values of t are equal to  2.3654985546995 \n Cannot calculate confidence intervals"
for boot.plot: [1] "All values of t* are equal to  2.3654985546995"

Now I do see/have researched relevant threads dealing with this issue, but none have provided a "one-size-fits-all" answer that I can tell. What's more, since 12 of the 15 boots are not generating this error, and I am changing absolutely nothing in the code except for relevant unique function/object identifiers (i.e., DIM1A_IRT_vars becomes DIM1B_IRT_vars etc.), I do not understand why this is happening for these three dimensions. I have also tried dropping the comments as a prior users had suggested but that did not change anything. Also, dropping return before (coef(fit)) does not change anything. Lastly, I have upped the bootstraps to 600 and this also did not change the results. All bootstrapped estimates just repeat the first estimate of the original sample as shown below for one of the dimensions which has 32 parameters (16 difficulty estimates and 16 discrimination estimates):

```
> bootDIM4A$t0[1:36]
 [1]  2.3654986  2.3543770  2.9894745  1.9730266  2.0989111  2.2333604  2.2546996  3.4546528  3.3797208  5.1105451  1.5078148 17.0628991  3.1567948
[14]  4.1629080  2.1770134  4.0014715  1.0831248  0.9757742  0.9994559  1.2374123  1.8756228  1.2023270  1.3513075  1.1867299  1.8608412  0.5105291
[27]  1.3291120  0.2202287  2.4495431  1.0526343  1.1105217  0.6287497         NA         NA         NA         NA

> bootDIM4A$t[1:200]
  [1] 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499
 [17] 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499
 [33] 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499
 [49] 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499
 [65] 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499
 [81] 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499
 [97] 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499
[113] 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499
[129] 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499
[145] 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499
[161] 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499
[177] 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499
[193] 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499 2.365499
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change your BS function to this:

```
BS <- function(data, indices) {

d <- data[indices, ] # allows boot to select sample

fit <- ltm(d ~ z1, IRT.param=TRUE, start.val="random", na.action=NULL, control=list(GHk=35, iter.em=100, verbose=TRUE))
  return(coef(fit))
      }
```

then use this:

```
boot(data="your actual dataset with item responses", statistic=BS, R=500, sim="ordinary")
```

This should work.

This is an example with `WIRS` data from `ltm` package:

```
> boot(data=WIRS, statistic=BS, R=500, sim="ordinary")    

ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP


Call:
boot(data = WIRS, statistic = BS, R = 500, sim = "ordinary")


Bootstrap Statistics :
       original      bias    std. error
t1*   3.4013781  7.52611046  59.3494490
t2*  -0.9421109 -0.01612312   0.8377384
t3*   0.8093891 -0.17794274   0.6883230
t4*   1.3688871 -0.24206685   0.8511538
t5*   0.4762308 -0.10135528   0.3921645
t6*   1.6804624 -0.35333454   1.2908451
t7*   0.1533959  0.06739873   1.0988324
t8*   0.3676942 -0.18417850   1.0817039
t9*   1.7178883 -0.28775229   0.9994516
t10*  1.0101366 -0.21218369   0.6517991
t11*  2.0330472 -0.30806809   1.2112776
t12*  1.3745729 -0.23506519   0.8087398
```

Since there are 6 items in the data set and the package estimates item difficulty and item discrimination parameters, the `boot` produces results for 12 parameters in the which the first six correspond to item difficulties  (i.e., t1* to t6*) and the rest correspond to item discriminations  (i.e., t7* to t12*).